# How to create teble 3 from data of table 1 and table 2

Tags: sql, oracle

t1 (ordered descending):

| a | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 512 | (ordered desc) |
| 415 |  |
| 310 |  |
| 205 |  |
| 195 |  |
| 150 |  |
| 132 |  |
| 90 |  |
| 74 |  |
| 20 |  |
| 1 |  |

t2 (ordered ascending):

| b | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | (ordered asc) |
| 11 |  |
| 12 |  |
| 13 |  |

I would like to create t3:

| a (desc) | b | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 512 | 10 | (b=asc) |
| 415 | 11 |  |
| 310 | 12 |  |
| 205 | 13 |  |
| 195 | 13 | (b=desc) |
| 150 | 12 |  |
| 132 | 11 |  |
| 90 | 10 |  |
| 74 | 10 | (b=asc) |
| 20 | 11 |  |
| 1 | 12 |  |

etc.

In table t3, a is data from t1, and b is data from t2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a sequence number and then join using arithmetic:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (order by a desc) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (order by which,
                                         case when which = 'a' then b end asc,
                                         b desc
                               ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t2 cross join
           (select 'a' as which from dual union all
            select 'd' as which from dual
           ) x
     ) t2
     on mod(t1.seqnum - 1, t2.cnt) = t2.seqnum - 1
order by t1.seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

This script is no different to Gordon Linoffs - I just find it easier to read

```
with cte_t1 as (select 512 as a from dual 
union select 415 from dual union select 310 from dual union select 205 from dual union select 195 from dual
union select 150 from dual union select 132 from dual union select 90   from dual union select 74 from dual 
union select 20 from dual union select 1 from dual
)
, cte_t2 as (select 10 as b from dual union select 11 from dual      union select 12 from dual union select 13 from dual
)
, cte_t1_seq as ( select cte_t1.*, row_number() over (order by a desc) as seqnum from cte_t1
)
, cte_t2_seq as (select cte_t2.*, x.which, 
             row_number() over (order by which,
                                         case when which = 'asc' then b end asc,
                                         b desc
                               ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from cte_t2 cross join
           (select 'asc' as which from dual union all
            select 'desc' as which from dual
           ) x
) 
-- , cte_bases as (select * from cte_t1_seq) select * from cte_bases 
select cte_t1_seq.a, cte_t2_seq.b, cte_t1_seq.seqnum as "t1_seq"
     , cte_t2_seq.seqnum as "t2_seq", cte_t2_seq.cnt
  from cte_t1_seq
  left join cte_t2_seq 
     on mod(cte_t1_seq.seqnum - 1, cte_t2_seq.cnt) = cte_t2_seq.seqnum - 1
order by cte_t1_seq.seqnum;
```